# Duck Duck go HTML version get next page of results url query param

Tags: duckduckgo

Is it possible to get the next page of results for a duck duck go search on the html version using a url query param?

Comment: I'd turn off JavaScript  in the browser and see what it serves - it'll likely give you a number of page links

Comment: I used bing in the end because I could get more results per page and then also go to the next page using the url params.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that with the right parameters, it is possible to get different pages from the `/html/` version of duckduckgo.com.

You need to specify:

- `q` for the search
- `s` for the offset of the current page (nothing for the first page)
- `dc` for the offset of the current page + 1 (start of the new page, nothing for the first page)
- `v` to the arbitrary value `l`
- `o` to the format `json`
- `api` to the endpoint `/d.js`

Which gives, given the search `$term` and the page `$n`:

```
https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=$term&s=$(($n*30))&dc=$(($n*30+1))&v=l&o=json&api=/d.js
```

And for the first page:

```
https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=$term&s=&dc=&v=l&o=json&api=/d.js
```

*Note 1: This can be used with both GET and POST HTML methods.*

*Note 2: According to my tests, it appears that the `s` and `dc` parameters need to respectively be a multiple of 30, and a multiple of 30, plus 1.*

HTH